# How do I Parse the google result to just get the names, latitudes and longitudes in a readable format?

Tags: python, google-maps

Please help,

I am running a query to find all the bars within a radius of a particular location. The code works to produce this result. 
However, this result is too difficult to actually get any information from. 
I need the geometry (lat and long) for each result and preferably the name too. I'd like this information to be automatically populated in a new dataframe, but even printing it would be perfect right now.

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
from googlemaps import convert

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='my_api_key_is_here')

query = 'bar'
location = (54.584520, -5.935232)
radius = 500

local = gmaps.places('bar', location = location, radius = radius)

#This is what I attempted
#print local['local']['results'][0]['titleNoFormatting']

print local
.... {u'results': {u'geometry': {u'location' {u'lat' 54.343434, u'lng': -5.23423423}}....} }
```

When I print it, it looks like the below image. How do I access the particular lat and long for each bar?

How do I access the following:

```
{u'geometry': {u'location' {u'lat' 54.343434, u'lng': -5.23423423}}....}
```

I'm very new to python so any extremely obvious help is appreciated!

Comment: Checkout json library of python, the result you are getting is JSON and once you get confortable with this format, it will be much easier to move forward. JSON is basically dictionaries and lists

Comment: Thank you @TusharAggarwal, any advice on where to start understanding JSON?

Comment: You can google json python tutorial and check out any site, basically what i think you need is just 2 functions for now : json.loads and json.dumps and of course an understanding of what JSON is

Comment: @TusharAggarwal great thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to iterate over the results.

You can access the geometry values by doing: bar["geometry"] and so forth.

```
local = gmaps.places('bar', location=location, radius=radius)
for bar in local['results']:
    loc = bar['geometry']['location']
    print(
        '{} ({}, {})'
        .format(bar['name'], loc['lon'], loc['lat'])
    )
```

You can read more about python dictionaries here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: This is the first question I've ever asked on this site and your response has honestly worked perfectly. I really appreciate it, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I wanted to provide more explanation but suddenly was short on time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're getting is a JSON object. It's data that's been structured into text; that means that it's a string until you actually parse it out into a Python object.

To turn it into to a Python dictionary, try the following:

```
import json

my_data = json.loads(local)
print(my_data['results'])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely have to check out json in detail

Comment: It already is a JSON object that is being returned from the `gmaps` call